# Errno22 while setting up django (trying to use get_template)

Tags: python, django, templates

I am using windows, new to Django, trying to learn it.

Right now I am just trying to set up a template, views, url - and load the template in my browser.  Should be simple.

I have a project folder.  An app folder.  A templates folder.  My templates folder contains page.html which is an html file that just says "hi".

my urls is properly configured to point to my views

I have 2 views.

```
def frontpage(request):

    fp = open('C:/EclipseWorkspace64/Project/templates/page.html')
    page = Template(fp.read())
    return HttpResponse(page)

def otherpage(request):
    page = get_template('page.html')
    return HttpResponse(page)
```

The first view loads my template fine when I go to the URL.
The second view does not.  It gives me: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\EclipseWorkspace64\Project\:\page.html'

This is templates in my settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': 'C:/EclipseWorkspace64/Project/templates/',
        'APP_DIRS': False,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I don't understand why I get this error.  What am I doing wrong?  Why does the first view load but the second one doesn't?  I have followed instructions in the django book on how to set up my settings file to a tee.

Comment: DIRS should be a list or tuple; does it work if you use `['C:/EclipseWorkspace64/Project/templates/'],`?

Comment: ah thank god.  yes that was the issue.  (though now the first view actually shows the html page including the text, and the first view just shows an empty page.. I don't know why but I am sure I can solve it)  I am guessing I need to render it or such but I suppose the tutorial will get to that.